# Get a^ib^jc^k from expand (a+b+c)^n

Tags: maple

I want to write a function `func(n)` get `a^ib^jc^k` from expand `(a+b+c)^n`.

Example :

When `n = 1` then `(a + b + c)^1 = a + b + c` and `func(n)` return `{a, b, c}`.

When `n = 2` then `(a + b + c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2ab + 2bc + 2ca` and `func(n)` return `{a^2, b^2, c^2, ab, bc, ca}`.

I have solution using three loops but in think it's not nice, someone can help me. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In maple to do some sort of programming you can use `proc` short for procedure.

```
restart:
ftn:= proc(n)
     expand((a+b+c)^n);
     {op(%)};
     end;
```

Now let's try to check whether we get what you want.

```
ftn(1);
```

> {a, b, c}

```
ftn(2);
```

> {a^2, b^2, c^2, 2*a*b, 2*a*c, 2*b*c}

If you do not want the constant coefficients of `ab`, `ac` and `bc` then you can do this

```
restart:
ftn:= proc(n)
     expand((a+b+c)^n);
     convert([coeffs(%,[a,b,c],'powers')],array):
    convert({powers},list);
     end;
ftn(2);
```

> [a^2, b^2, c^2, a*b, a*c, b*c]

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Comment: @Fzen If this an answer to your question then accept it is an answer?

Comment: Your answer was what I wanted. Thanks you.